# Starting Kibana - "No such container: monitoring-x.x.x.x"

Tags: bluedata, bluedata-3.7

I'm working through the [BlueData docs](http://docs.bluedata.com/37_accessing-kibana-monitoring) to enable Kibana.

> To start Kibana:
>
> 1. Login to the Controller.
> 2. Execute the command `docker exec -it monitoring-<controller_ip> bash`, where `<controller_ip>` is the IP address of the Controller.
> 3. ...

I've ssh'd into my BlueData controller and run the `docker exec ...` command, however, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: monitoring-10.1.0.26
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

---

**NOTE**: My BlueData version is `bluedata-epic-entdoc-minimal-release-3.7-2207`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check what containers are running:

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          ...    NAMES
60287e139b54        epic/webhdfs:1.0               ...    epic-webhdfs-10.1.0.26
90f73bb7a37e        epic/monitoring:1.4            ...    epic-monitoring-10.1.0.26
a55758993978        epic/nagios:1.5                ...    epic-nagios-10.1.0.26
309d9084df5a        epic/apache-hdfs-centos:2.7.2  ...    epic-apache-hdfs-centos
```

You can now see the correct command:

```sh
$ docker exec -it epic-monitoring-10.1.0.26 bash
```

The documentation appears to be missing the `epic-` suffix, i.e.

Instead of ...

```sh
$ docker exec -it monitoring-<controller_ip> bash
```

It looks like it should be ...

```sh
$ docker exec -it epic-monitoring-<controller_ip> bash
```